# adding nested vector column by column

Tags: c++, vector

So lets say I have nested vector

```
6 7 8 9 10

5 6 7 8 9
 
4 5 6 7 8 

10 11 12 12 12
```

they are in a data nested vector and I want to add them column by column and push them in a sumV vector.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
       sum = 0; 
       for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++ ){
           
           sum = sum + j; 
           
           
       }
       
       sumV.push_back(sum); 
   }
```

But it seems giving me the wrong values.

Comment: *But it seems giving me the wrong values.* -- What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I  add each element column by column?  for example (6+ 5 + 4 + 10)  should be the first sum.

Comment: Step through your code. You aren't accessing your data, you're just calculating summed triangular numbers. For example, if i (data.size) = 4, you are doing 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10, then pushing 10 to your new vector. You need to access the numbers inside your data vector.

Comment: I should have done  sum = sum + data[j]?

Comment: @MosrourTafadar Usage of `std::accumulate` makes this a two line solution, with no hand-rolled addition being done.  Are you willing to see how it's done using `std::accumulate`?

Comment: I would love to.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all of the nested vectors have equal size, you can get the sum of the columns by using [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) within a loop.

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Test case
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v = {{6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
                                       {5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
                                       {4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
                                       {10, 11, 12, 12, 12}};

    // The final sum vector  
    std::vector<int> sum;

    // loop for each column
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v[0].size(); ++i)
    {   
        // add up the i'th column and store in sum
        sum.push_back(std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, 
                     [&](int total, std::vector<int>& current) 
                                               { return current[i] + total; }));
    }

    // Output results
    for(auto val : sum)
       std::cout << val << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
25
29
33
36
39
```